# getattr(__builtins__,'int') not working in web2py

Tags: python, web2py, built-in

When I run `getattr(__builtins__,'int')` on Python console I get `<type 'int'>` as output. But when I write same line in my web2py application's module I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'int'.
```

I tried to check type of `__builtins__` at python console and it showed type as module whereas in web2py it is treating it as a dict. Please let me know how do I make it work.

Comment: Simple. Rewrite web2py.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a class for defining parameter. It contains its type, length, format, etc. I am trying to assign integer/string/other to type member of some objects of this class. eval('int') worked for me, but I guess getattr should be the preferred way to do this.

Comment: Why can't you just use `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__builtins__` is an implementation detail. What you want is the confusingly similarly-named `__builtin__` module, which you can get with `import __builtin__`.